# Unable to add UIImageView Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

For some reason I am unable to add a UIImageView to my app. This is the code I am using and I have searched for quite a while to figure this out but haven't had any luck.

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cloudimage = UIImage(named: "cloud")
    let cloudView = UIImageView(image: cloudimage)
    self.view.addSubview(cloudView)
    cloudView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)
```

The image is a .png in my assets folder so I don't think it's that. I do have auto layout settings enabled if that is an issue? I know it can be an issue with moving a UIImageView around by using its frame, but I think I should still be able to place the image in the View no problem with this code.

I am not quite sure what to do any suggestions would be great, this is extremely frustrating.

Comment: what debugging have you done?

Comment: Is there any debugging available? Does it crash or does it just not show the imageView? Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Your code is working for me.Check whether image is present in assets or otherwise add normally.

Comment: move your frame set line before addsubview.

Comment: It shows my subview behind my background image which is also part of the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is `nil`, your `UIImageView` will not render anything. Try debug your view hierarchy.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: Alright I somewhat figured out the debug mode (I'm fairly new to Xcode if it isn't obvious). It appears that my UIImageView is showing up behind another subview? Is there any way to bring this to the front somehow.

Comment: After trying the following code:  `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(cloudView)`  It still shows it behind another uiimageview which is my background. Not sure why ;/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add UIimageview to main view.

self.view.addSubview(cloudView)

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving the image extension also while setting to `UIImage`

```
    let cloudimage = UIImage(named: "cloud.png")
    let cloudView = UIImageView(image: cloudimage)
    cloudView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)
    self.view.addSubview(cloudView)
```

Checked and its working.

Comment: cloudView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200) is more convenient to use before  self.view.addSubview(cloudView).

Comment: Aright I tried adding the extension as well as putting the frame setup before adding the subview but it still isn't showing up :/ It is stuck behind another uiimageview not sure why. I tried using self.view.bringSubviewToFront(cloudView) as well. Still no luck.